# TypeScript type inference issue with string literal

Tags: typescript, type-inference

In a react-native application, I have the style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        textAlign: "center"
    },
})
```

used in `<Text style={styles.text} />`, but the `tsc` compiler gives the following error:

```
Types of property 'textAlign' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"center" | "auto" | "left" | "right"'.
```

The definition of `TextStyle` in `@types/react-native` includes:

```
export interface TextStyle extends TextStyleIOS, TextStyleAndroid, 
ViewStyle {
    // ...
    textAlign?: "auto" | "left" | "right" | "center"
    // ...
}
```

Why is the compiler complaining about incompatibility? It seems that it is inferring the type of `textAlign` to be the too general `string` instead of checking the actual value (`"center"`).

I know that I can use a `as TextStyle` to avoid the problem, but I would like to know why it is happening and if I should file a ticket against the compiler.

Comment: or maybe the typings mantainer, as it seems the expected values is not a string...

Comment: I think the typings maintainer is correct in limiting the values, but the compiler should carry the actual value through to type comparison instead of inferring `string`. Otherwise, what is the purpose of having string literal types?

Comment: You're correct indeed, it seems a tsc error then.. :/

Comment: Finding the same issue, I used to have code like this that worked, which is now broken - think it's tsc issue

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        textAlign: "center" as "center"
    },
})
```

Normally TypeScript would type textAlign as string, but since it can't just be any string, you can cast it to the more specific type.

Comment: I can also use `text: { ... } as TextStyle`, but I still think the compiler should handle that.

Answer (score 25):

If you're using Typescript 3.4+ you can make use of the `as const` notation:

```
export const locationInput = {
  textAlign: 'center' as const
};
```

For more info check [documentations here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

Answer (score 6):

Another option whould be:

```
import { TextAlignProperty } from 'csstype'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        textAlign: "center" as TextAlignProperty
    },
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it really is exactly what I needed! :)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do similiar in **React TypeScript** and the answers here are close but were not quite the working solution.  Instead I found I had to **import Property from csstype**, and then cast as **Property.TextAlign.**

In the below Example I call to a function that returns Property.TextAlign instead of a regular string.

```
import { Property } from 'csstype'

...

const getTextAlign = (dataType: string):Property.TextAlign => {
    var output:string = "left";

    if(dataType === "Money"){
        output = "right";
    }

    return output as Property.TextAlign;
}

...

<td style={{textAlign: getTextAlign(this.state.dataType) }}>
```

***Trying to follow the other solutions, I just got an error that TextAlignProperty wasn't defined in csstype.***  Here I was particularly working in a PCF control, but that shouldn't matter.  This may be a difference due to version of React.