# Typescript union type string is not loaded from JSON

Tags: json, typescript, webpack

I have json file `test.json`

```js
{ "foo": "bar0" }
```

Given those types declaration

```js
type Bar = 'bar0' | 'bar1'

interface Foo {
    foo: Bar
}
```

I tried to load this json

```js
import test from './test.json'

const foo: Foo = test
```

And I got this error

```sh
Type '{ "foo": string; }' is not assignable to type 'Foo'.
  Types of property 'foo' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Bar'.
```

I also tried with enum

```js
enum Bar {
    bar0 = 'bar0',
    bar1 =  'bar1'
}
```

Of course it works with `type Bar = string`

Any idea about what can be wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript type inference issue with string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121661/typescript-type-inference-issue-with-string-literal)

Comment: I am trying to load JSON, it's quite different

Comment: TypeScript is inferring your JSON property `foo` is a string, while your type `Bar` is a string literal. It's the same problem but just different ways of getting it.

Comment: You need first of all do JSON.parse, and second you need to do as Foo.

Comment: @Bauke The solution suggests to cast the "center" object as 'as "center"' while I do not see how I could cast it. Are suggesting that I could use a temporary object

Comment: This is rather old but it came up in a search for the issue. You would cast it as follows: `const foo: Foo = test as Foo`